# c# wpf show previous active window when closing current app

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a c# wpf application I wrote that launches from an application that I didn't write (long story) and I want the focus to go back to the application that launches my application when I close mine.  Currently, if I have several applications maximized behind the one I launch my application launches from, when I close my application, one of the other applications will show instead of the one I launched from....if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to import these DLLs:

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

and put this is in you Window Closed event handler:

```
IntPtr iHandle = FindWindow(null, "title_bar_text_of_first_program");
if (iHandle != IntPtr.Zero) SetForegroundWindow(iHandle);
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry it took me so long to reply, my error was coming from the parent application, I now have it resolved.  Thanks again.